# OSX Touch Command -- Broken?

Tags: macos, bash

This feels like a silly question, but my `touch` command seems to have broken. Trying to create the `~/.bash_profile` file using the command: `touch ~/.bash_profile` and seeing the following when I send the command: `-bash: touch: No such file or directory.` I've search quite a bit for an answer but haven't found the same problem so far. Can anyone assist? What exactly do I need to do in order to make the touch command work?

Comment: If you do `which touch`, what do you see?

Comment: Then I have no idea what's going on.  Bash knows which `touch` to call, but yet claims it doesn't exist...

Comment: I managed to work around the problem by separately creating .bash_profile in another editor, but the problem is frustrating!

Comment: how about `touch "$HOME/.bash_profile"`?

Comment: try typing in "`unalias touch`" at the prompt and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Try `file /usr/bin/touch` to make sure the command itself hasn't been replaced by something else (it should reply with something like "/usr/bin/touch: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64" in OS X 10.8, probably a bit different in earlier versions).

Comment: Side question, but why do you want to create an empty file with `touch`?

Comment: Unalias command didn't work. I see this: "-bash: unalias: touch: not found." Concerning creating an empty file, hoping to edit it with VIM, or was hoping.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` give you?

Comment: Who is the user under the tilde? Maybe your current user does not have a home directory?

Comment: If you want to create a new file using VIM, just enter `vim ~/.bash_profile` and edit. End with `:wq` and VIM will create the file. Alternatively, if you need an empty file but don't want to edit it immediately, you can use `: > ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 5):

You might like to run the `touch` command through OS X's equivalent of `strace` (I think that command exists on OS X, actually, although there appear to be others), go through the output and examine what errors are generated, if any. Pasting the output to a pastebin may also be a good idea.

I think this is one of those instances where the call to `strerror()` inside `touch`'s C code is referencing an insane value of `errno`. (This is where all those "*Error performing `<X>`: Success*" messages come from. There was an error, but `errno` subsequently got set to `0` by a successful command before `errno` was captured and the error message printed.)

Comment: Interesting idea. No `strace` on OS X though.

Comment: Ah. I think you want DTrace. [This looks like an interesting overview](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) of the various commandline options available; alternatively, if you have Xcode installed, you also apparently get Instruments, some kind of GUI that interacts with the DTrace service.

Comment: Okay, it's `iosnoop` and requires `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

I have OS X Mavericks, and I use Kornshell, but I'll switch over to bash:

Let's try touching a non-existent file:

```
$ touch foo
```

Nope. That worked. Let's try touching a file you don't own:

```
$ touch /usr/bin/true
touch true: Permission denied
```

Nope, that's what I expected and not what the OP got. Let's try with a symbolic link

```
ln -s foo bar
touch bar
```

Nope, worked. Let's try it with a directory:

```
$ touch Applications
```

Nope, also worked.

Try this:

```
$ sum /usr/bin/touch
6205 9 /usr/bin/touch
$ file /usr/bin/touch
/usr/bin/touch: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

If you're using Mavericks, I assume you should get the same results.